# How to Configure Django on Gunicorn and Nginx (Mac OS X)

Tags: django, nginx, operating-system, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm trying to set up Django with Nginx + Gunicorn and Supervisor in Lion.
I have already installed:

**Progress**: MySQL DMG + MySQLdb Compile + Python + brew nginx + easy_install gunicorn + pip install Django + easy_install supervisor.

**Current configuration details:**

```
Nginx:
upstream app_server {
     server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    #Static
    root /Users/andre/sites;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Gunicorn: You can see [Here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py)

```
Supervisor:
[program:gunicorn]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn main:application -c    /Users/devepy/desktop/andre/andre/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/Users/andre/desktop/andre/myproject
user=nobody
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
```

Actually I have no idea what else to do, but it took weeks trying to learn mac osx is crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you must have resolved it by now but I came across a very good blog that might help you.
http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/01/27/deploy-django-nginx-gunicorn-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [tutorial](https://github.com/zachvalenta/nginx-wsgi) about how to wire up Nginx to Gunicorn and Gunicorn to a WSGI app (meaning, Django, Flask, Tornado, et al.)

In short:

- bind Gunicorn to your app: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi`
- update `nginx.conf` to pass requests to Gunicorn

  ```
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
  ```

If you think more details from the tutorial would make this answer more helpful, leave a comment and I'll update here.